# Entity Framework 6 delete all rows that are not present in update request

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm using asp core razor pages with Entity Framework 6,  I have 3 model classes Project, ProjectLineItem and ProjectVendor

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the razor page, users can enter project details and add multiple line items and tag multiple vendors to each line item.The razor page is
 [image]

I pass form data as JSON and bind to the model class Project. On creating and edit I have all the data in the class 'Project'. On Edit view if the user deletes the project line item, It will be removed from JSON.So on the update, I want to delete all projectLineItem and ProjectVenodor rows that are not present in the class "Project".Is there any alternative way in Entity Framework Code First approach for removing deleted line items from the database, instead of selecting all entries of Project and looping it in and compare with update data?

Comment: At a guess, make the project lines "owned": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#collections-of-owned-types

Comment: I guess you can set it up as cascade on delete and delete the parent. All the children will be deleted. Then you save the new modified items sent as JSON. Although it seems Jacky. The other approach is to write a stores procedure and pass the IDs of the items not to be deleted, and in the stored procedure delete all the rest. After the stored procedure returns, save the modified items.

Comment: @CodingYoshi cascade will work with ProjectLineItem and ProjectVendor.We are not deleting Project so we can't use it there

Comment: Doesn't matter if you're not deleting `Project`, delete it. You have it with the new children so you can save it again. But if something needs `Project` (foreign key) aside from its children, then you cannot. Then use a stored procedure.